# Fabric on Kuberntes without chaincode as a service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

It is possible to use external builders and launchers, but not to use ccaas, so I don't have to modify my actual chaincode and I could deploy it on K8s?
Is there any example with java script chaincode so I can use those external builders?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [fabric-builder-k8s](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fabric-builder-k8s) project. This does change the way you package the chaincode but should not require any change to the actual chaincode implementation itself.

Fabric-builder-k8s uses a custom builder (registered with the Fabric peer) to allow Fabric to spin up the chaincode container as a Kubernetes pod (from a published Docker image containing your chaincode implementation) in a similar way that the default chaincode builder spins up Docker containers from the chaincode implementation bundled within your chaincode package.